# How get property of generic type correctly?

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

How get property of Interface? When it's generic parameter.

```
public enum PersonType
{
    Customer,
    Client,
}
public interface IPerson
{
    PersonType type { get; }
}

public class Customer : IPerson
{
    public PersonType type => PersonType.Customer;
}

public class Client : IPerson
{
    public PersonType type => PersonType.Client;
}

public class PersonHelper<T> where T : IPerson
{
    public PersonHelper()
    {
        //Is it good to take enum type of T with reflection?
        var k = typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments[0].GetProperty("type");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Sure you can lookup what properties are available in a type, but you're not going to be able to figure out the saved value because it's an instance member (like `type` is).

Comment: @gunr2171 I want to get type of incoming interface (T)

Comment: Then it's just `typeof(T)`. I don't understand what else you're trying to do.

Comment: `T` is constrained to `IPerson`, so anything declared as `T` has a `type` property accessible without reflection. But as gunr2171 said, you have no instance to access so far. If your constructor were to have a `T person` parameter, you could access `person.type` directly. But now you have to ask yourself, why not just deal with `IPerson` directly? Why do you need it to be generic?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't. `type` is an *instance* property: I could write:

```
public class BadPerson : IPerson
{
    public PersonType type { get; } = Random.Shared.Next(2) == 0
        ? Person.Customer
        : Person.Client;
}
```

What then? `BadPerson` doesn't have a single type -- the type will be different each each `new BadPerson()` that you create. You have to ask what type an *instance* of `BadPerson` has, rather than what type the `BadPerson` *type* has.

---

However, .NET 7 is introducing [static abstract properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/#static-abstracts-in-interfaces). This will let you define *static* members in interfaces, and static members are associated with the type, rather than an instance of the type.

```
public interface IPerson
{
    static abstract PersonType Type { get; }
}

public class Customer : IPerson
{
    public static PersonType Type => PersonType.Customer;
}

public class PersonHelper<T> where T : IPerson
{
    public PersonHelper()
    {
        var k = T.Type;
    }
}
```

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBTAKYDuABAArXIDOA9jABLUA2ADiwA8AYVSsE7MCwB8ACgCUAbgoV8AZnrUYqMExYcYAFQCegigG8K9G/TESpLONdsjeUbQgoBfVeQ30sAgsAGYQAMbU9ACSzGycli42+MQAbPQQwBLIEQj68cZmUaaC9Bb0AObUCEr0vuT1appEduKS0sj0IDFxhonktvQBKem9nCXFRfQAvDL5hhMAdPbtLCoNfsOE85w8AsJGc7QAFizFXT0GCeRWA7YBY9x8gsiKSWXvgwBuEJ0A1jN6EZFhN1oN6t4gA===).

This feature is currently in preview -- see the linked post for instructions on enabling preview features.